# Git cola not working in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, git

when running git-cola through terminal it returns an error with the following 
/usr/bin/python3: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0' with`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
/usr/bin/python3: Relink`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol`clock_gettime'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)